# Python is using the wrong version of Numpy module

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, version

I'm trying to use Numpy 1.11.1 for Python 2.7. I have Mac El Capitan, so `sudo pip install` doesn't work.

I decided to install Homebrew and do `brew install python` and that worked. If I use `pip show numpy` it shows that I have Numpy 1.11.1 now.

But if I run `python -c 'import numpy; print numpy.version.version'` I still get `1.8.0rc1` which is the old version I was trying to upgrade!

How do I use the correct numpy module? I would like to do this in a way that doesn't require adding in a line to the python scripts that call numpy, but if that's the only way then I'll do it.

info:

```
which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip
which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip
which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip3
which python
/usr/bin/python
which python2
which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
which python3.5
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a **[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)** to install the required libraries version. Don't pollute your system Python.

It will solve your problem…

```
mkdir $HOME/virtualenv
cd $HOME/virtualenv
virtualenv my_app
source my_app/bin/activate
pip install the_lib==x.y.z
```

Where *the_lib* is **numpy** and *x.y.z* is the version **1.11.1**.

Comment: Okay, I will learn virtualenv. It seems like it's what I need. Thank you.